# Why does useRef solve the problem of stale state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am aware of the issue of stale state in nested functions or callbacks (e.g. setTimeout) inside a React component. For example, in the code below (take from React docs) we see the issue of stale state:

> "If you first click “Show alert” and then increment the counter, the
> alert will show the count variable at the time you clicked the “Show
> alert” button."

```
function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  function handleAlertClick() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert('You clicked on: ' + count);
    }, 3000);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
      <button onClick={handleAlertClick}>
        Show alert
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I know that we can create a mutable reference to the most up to date/current value of state by using `useRef`:

```
function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const stateRef = useRef()
  stateRef.current = count
  function handleAlertClick() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert('You clicked on: ' + stateRef.current);
    }, 3000);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
      <button onClick={handleAlertClick}>
        Show alert
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My question is, why does creating a reference to our `useRef` variable (`stateRef`) solve the problem of stale state, and why does this get around the issue of closure? Surely by just referencing `count` directly inside `setTimeout`, once the component re-renders the `count` value will have updated, and therefore our reference to it would return the up to date value.

I am struggling to understand why referencing `stateRef` as opposed to `count` gets around the issue of stale state, given they are both declared in the same lexical scope from `setTimeout`s point of view.

Comment: Since ref is just an object, there is no closure on **object's values**, its not related to React, just Javascript, reading about closures should explain it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try imagine a timeline, each re-render of your component creates a "snapshot" and leaves a mark on this timeline.

So called "stale state" is more often referred as "stale closure", which more accurately describes the real problem.

How precisely closure causes trouble?

Each time a component re-render, the component function itself is re-executed from start to end, and during this execution:

1. all the hook calls along the way are called
2. all the **local variables** are re-initialzed
3. and all the **nested functions** inside the component function are re-declared
4. and MOST IMPORTANTLY, if any of these nested functions reference the local variables within the component function, such reference is really pointing to a "closure", or a "snapshot" that captures the current states of those local variables, created on-the-fly and stored somewhere inside memory.

If you call `setTimeout` and send a callback function to it, and that function references a local variable, it's really stored inside one of these snapshots on the rendering timeline.

As the component re-renders, new snapshots are added to the timeline and only the latest one is up-to-date, while as the callback function is still referencing a stale snapshot/closure.

By the time `setTimeout` decide to execute the callback, the callback look at its own version of snapshot/closure and say "OK, the 'count' variable is 0" unaware of it's stale.

How `useRef` solves the problem?

Cus `const ref = useRef()` always returns the same object reference across re-rendering. So even if callback look at a stale snapshot/closure, it still sees the same object `ref` as in the latest snapshot. And since each re-execution of the component function always sets the `ref.value = someValue` property with latest value, the callback got a way to access the latest value.

Answer (score 1):

> Surely by just referencing count directly inside setTimeout, once the
> component re-renders the count value will have updated, and therefore
> our reference to it would return the up to date value.

No, when you clicked on the button, the function `useSetTimeout` used the callback at hand at that time. And `count` is NOT a reference to your variable. When the component rerenders, the callback won’t know you changed the value at all.

`useRef` is different in this that it returns an object and objects work a bit differently than other types of variables. And since it’s always the same object, you’ll always deal with the same variable.

By the way, when you call `setCount`, be sure to always do `setCount(prevState => ...)`. Otherwise you’re not guaranteed to have the latest value.